XAML element to print
Issue how to print a xaml element
How to access printer and print an xaml element. A page choose from navigation view.
I am using winui-3 and c++20. Created a blank app

The idea is only to print my page not the hole window

Tried
I have tried to use PrintManager but it seem not to work with winui3. See source code. I am blank what to do now!
Source code
file: MainWindow.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="PrintingFrameworkElement.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PrintingFrameworkElement"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PrintingFrameworkElement">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="I should not be printed" Margin="10"/>
            <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Print</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <NavigationView 
            x:Name="NavControl" 
            PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
            IsSettingsVisible="False"
            ItemInvoked="OnNavigationViewItemInvoked">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="Page 1" Icon="Page" Tag="PrintingFrameworkElement.PageOne"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <Frame x:Name="NavContent" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
                <!-- NavigationView Content that shpuold be printable-->
            </Frame>
        </NavigationView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

file: MainWindow.xaml.h
#pragma once

#include "MainWindow.g.h"

namespace winrt::PrintingFrameworkElement::implementation
{
    struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow>
    {
        MainWindow()
        {
            // Xaml objects should not call InitializeComponent during construction.
            // See https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/nuget#initializecomponent
        }

        void myButton_Click(IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);

        void OnNavigationViewItemInvoked(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& /*sender*/, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs const& e);
        void NavigateToPage(hstring const& pageName);
    };
}

namespace winrt::PrintingFrameworkElement::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow, implementation::MainWindow>
    {
    };
}


file: MainWindow.xaml.cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("MainWindow.g.cpp")
#include "MainWindow.g.cpp"
#endif

#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Printing.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h>
//#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Printing.PrintManager.h>
//#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Printing.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace winrt::PrintingFrameworkElement::implementation
{
    void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        // Do printing of the FrameworkElement here
        using namespace winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml;
        using namespace winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Printing;

        // Create PrintDocument
        PrintDocument printDoc = PrintDocument();

        // Create a XAML element to print
        auto content = NavContent().Content().as<FrameworkElement>();

        // FIXME: This is not working
        // Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBAD0BFB4C (KernelBase.dll) in PrintingFrameworkElement.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80040155 : 'Interface not registered'.
        // Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBAD0BFB4C in PrintingFrameworkElement.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x000000F8A09D9DA8.
        //auto printManager = Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager::GetForCurrentView();

        //// Register for PrintTaskRequested event
        //printManager.PrintTaskRequested([=](Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager const&, Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs const& args)
        //    {
        //        Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTask task = args.Request().CreatePrintTask(L"Print Document",
        //            [](Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTask const& sender, Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs const& e)
        //            {
        //                e.SetSource(sender.Source());
        //            });
        //    });

        // Start the print process
        //Windows::Graphics::Printing::PrintManager::ShowPrintUIAsync();


        // New approach


        printDoc.Paginate([](IInspectable const&, PaginateEventArgs const& args)
            {
                // Create custom print logic
            });

        printDoc.GetPreviewPage([](IInspectable const&, GetPreviewPageEventArgs const& args)
            {
                // Provide preview page logic
            });

        printDoc.AddPages([](IInspectable const&, AddPagesEventArgs const& args)
            {
                // Add content pages to print
            });
    }
    void MainWindow::OnNavigationViewItemInvoked(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs const& e)
    {
        auto invokedItemContainer = e.InvokedItemContainer().as<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItem>();
        auto tag = winrt::unbox_value_or<hstring>(invokedItemContainer.Tag(), L"");
        auto type = winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName{ tag, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeKind::Metadata };
        NavContent().Navigate(type);
    }
    void MainWindow::NavigateToPage(hstring const& pageName)
    {
        // Find the NavigationViewItem with the specified tag
        for (auto const& item : NavControl().MenuItems())
        {
            if (auto navItem = item.try_as<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItem>())
            {
                if (winrt::unbox_value_or<hstring>(navItem.Tag(), L"") == pageName)
                {
                    // Set the selected item
                    NavControl().SelectedItem(navItem);
                    // Navigate to the page
                    auto type = winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName{ pageName, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeKind::Metadata };
                    NavContent().Navigate(type);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Updated 2
What s working

Getting HWND for active window

// file: MainWindow.xaml.cpp
...
#include <Printmanagerinterop.h>
...
// Manually define CLSID_PrintManager
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_PrintManager, 0x92788047, 0x3b5e, 0x41c7, 0x86, 0x2e, 0x4c, 0xd3, 0x0d, 0x45, 0xa3, 0x10);
...
    void printFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement const& element)
    {
        using namespace winrt::Windows::Graphics::Printing;
        using namespace Windows::Graphics::Printing;
        using namespace winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Printing;

        // Retrieve the window handle (HWND) of the current WinUI 3 window.
        // @see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/ui-input/retrieve-hwnd
        auto windowNative{ this->m_inner.as<::IWindowNative>() };
        HWND hWnd{ nullptr };
        windowNative->get_WindowHandle(&hWnd);

        if (!hWnd)
        {
            OutputDebugStringW(L"Failed to retrieve the window handle of the current WinUI 3 window.");
            return;
        }

        // Initialize COM library
        HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"Failed to initialize COM library.\n");
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of IPrintManagerInterop
        com_ptr<IPrintManagerInterop> printManagerInterop;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PrintManager, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(printManagerInterop.put()));
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"Failed to create instance of IPrintManagerInterop.\n");
            return;
        }



        // Register for the PrintTaskRequested event
        printManager.PrintTaskRequested({ this, &MainWindow::OnPrintTaskRequested });
    }

Failed to create instance of IPrintManagerInterop.
Thinking the problem could be with CLSID_PrintManager!
Download source code
https://github.com/Tirsvad/stackoverflow_79283567

You can use the GetForWindow method to get the PrintManager for the specified window. Refer to the Doc:Print from your app

@Jeaninez-MSFT
Tried something like printManagerInterop->GetForWindow(hWnd, __uuidof(IPrintManagerInterop), printManager); // comes with error
But still I do not know how to handle print in winui3 c++

Whether have you refered to the Doc:Print from your app The topic describes how to print from a Windows app.

@Jeaninez-MSFT A I am using c++ lots of the documentation is in C3 which I do not know how to translate to c++. Some of the methods requires other attribues and so on...

Try to use CLSID_PrintManagerInterop instead of CLSID_PrintManager.
